# how do i use factorial inside 'for' statement?

Tags: c, factorial

I am trying to use two factorials so that they can be used again to find another value. for example `fact1` is `(2n)!` and `fact2` is `(2n -1)!` and I want to use them in the following

```
(fx = (pow(x,(4*n+1))/((4*n+1)*fact1)) - (pow(x, (4*n -1)))/((4*n -1)*fact2))
```

and make it so that `fx` is added onto itself as `n` increases so I've put all of them under one `for` statement however when I print the numbers even the factorials come out wrong and I was wondering where I made the mistake, I haven't finished coding but found out it was wrong even before that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, b, n, fact1 = 1, fact2 = 1;
    float fx, fx1 = 0, erfc;
    float x;

    printf("enter the value for x\n");
    scanf("%f", &x);

    for (n = 1; n <= 5; n++)
    {
        for (c = 1; c <= (2 * n); c++)
            fact1 = fact1 * c;

        for (c = 1; c <= (2 * n - 1); c++)
            fact2 = fact2 * c;
        fx = (pow(x, (4 * n + 1)) / ((4 * n + 1) * fact1)) - (pow(x, (4 * n - 1))) / ((4 * n - 1) * fact2);
        fx1 = fx1 + fx;
    }

    printf("factorial of  = %d\n", fact1);
    printf("factorial of  = %d\n", fact2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never seem to be using `fx` and `fx1` anywhere?

Comment: You should _either_ reset the factorials to 1 before the `c = 1` loop _or_ calculate the factorials without the inner loop, based on the old value of `n`. By not resetting `fact1` and `fact2`, you will overflow quickly.

Comment: You can optimize the calculation of the factorials. `fact1 = (2n)! = (2n-1)! * 2n = fact1 * 2n` or `fact1(n) = fact1(n-1) * (2n-1) * 2n` and `fact2(n) = fact2(n-1) * (2n-2) * (2n-1)`